# C# custom Format Provider for any INumber value?

Tags: c#, formatting, number-formatting

Really new to this, but trying to implement a CustomFormater class `ICustomFormatter`
The idea is pretty simple but I cannot get it to work without adding hundred of `if` statements.

Format "K" should output the value divided by 1024, but whatever that value `type` is, it could be a `int`, `ulong`, `decimal` and so on, any value that implements `INumeric`

```
public class myFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {
  public object? GetFormat(Type? formatType) => formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
  public string Format(string? format, object? arg, IFormatProvider? formatProvider) {
    formatProvider ??= this;
    if (!Equals(formatProvider)) return string.Empty;
    if (arg == null) return string.Empty;
    string resultString = arg.ToString() ?? "";

    if (format.StartsWith('K')) {
      resultString = string.Format("{0:#,0.0} {1}", (double)arg / 1024, format);
    }

    return resultString;
  }
}
```

But as you could guess, it throws `InvalidCastException` when arg cannot be converted to `double`.   How do I make it generic? for any given value it would always be divisible by 1024 right?

```
    var fp = new myFormatter();
    Debug.WriteLine($"{fp.Format("K", 1024d, fp)}"); // Works fine
    Debug.WriteLine($"{fp.Format("K", 1024, fp)}");  // Fails
```

PS: And yes, I know there are several diff types to convert a number to K and classes/helpers for it, but I just need this simple one and I will implement other formats on my formatter as well.

Comment: You may check if arg implements IConvertible and if call ToDouble via that interface. If not add proper Error handling still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "cast" an `object` to `double` unless the underlying value is *actually* a double. The same syntax is used for *conversion* if the variable type is implicitly convertible, but there is no implicit conversion from `object` to `double`

`Convert.ToDouble` can convert at runtime, though:

```
if (format.StartsWith('K')) {
  resultString = string.Format("{0:#,0.0} {1}", Convert.ToDouble(arg) / 1024d, format);
}
```

Now the conversion will happen at runtime, and will fail if the value cannot be converted (e.g. a string value that does not represent a valid number).  You'll have to decide how to deal with those cases.

Note that I changed the denominator to a double value also to make the math more straightforward.

Comment: That seems to work, but is this the proper way of doing it? Wont Convert.ToDouble trim or limit my original value if its too big? I was able to make it work except for Int128 values.

Comment: It will do the same thing that an implicit conversion would do for types that can be implicitly converted.  If you want the largest possible range then you could use `Convert.ToDecimal` instead. It's not exactly clear what scenario you're concerned about.